# Replacing the entries in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame of dimension 100 by 54, where the rows are stock values at the end of the week, and each column represents a stock. I want to replace each entry in my data frame with the return value of the stock, so divide the current value of the cell by the previous one, and replace the current value by the new value. Example: Say I have this data frame with these values,

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo7pL.jpg)

I want to manipulate my data frame to be:

[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Klg.jpg)

So that it can eventually look like this:

[table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBuf.png)

I have written this as my code, but it does not do that job. I was wondering if someone can help me.

```
Returns99 <- NULL

for(i in 2:100){
  Returns99 <- rbind(Returns99, rep(NA, 54))
  Returns <- rbind(Returns99, (df100[i, ]/df100[i-1,]))
                   
}
```

Where df100 is the data frame with price entries.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop. With `Base R`,

```
rbind(NA, df100[-1,] / df100[-nrow(df100),])
```

gives,

```
        AGG       DBC       DFE
1        NA        NA        NA
2 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
3 1.0021019 0.9739496 0.9990862
4 0.9993008 1.0008628 0.9911585
```

**Data:**

```
structure(list(AGG = c(99.91, 99.91, 100.12, 100.05), DBC = c(23.8, 
23.8, 23.18, 23.2), DFE = c(65.66, 65.66, 65.6, 65.02)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Initially, it kept giving me an error, but it turned out one of my columns had `chr` type, so I changed it to numeric and your recommendation worked!

Comment: @pamfromdundermifflin Good to hear that. If it solves the issue, please accept the answer. You can see the details in here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .